# How to plot names based on two numbers (x,y axes) on a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Have tried to solve this by scouring the internet but am not having any success with IF and VLOOKUP statements, so thought I'd try here.

This is for a stakeholder analysis. Sheet one is where stakeholder names are entered along with meaningful values. I would like the names to be automatically displayed on the matrix on sheet two. This will involve a formula that pulls in the stakeholder name to a cell based on the values in the columns 'Sub total A' (Y axis) and 'Sub total B' (X axis).

Please see images attached below (believe they'll be hosted elsewhere, as I don't have permission to upload them here yet).

Also, how could two or more names be displayed if they correspond to the same cell?

Thanks in advance for your help :D

[Sheet 1 – data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi5pp.png)

[Sheet 2 – matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY4wq.png)

UPDATE: Have created a work around, using excels built in chart function. Requires labels to be manually shown then text added. The elements around the chart have been added manually.

[Scatter chart workaround (manually labelled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8ZRf.png)

Comment: Will there be names with exactly the same x- and y-values? If there are, it adds a great deal of complexity. BTW, your data table and matrix disagree on this question for e.g. name 3, name 4, name 8 and name 9.

Comment: Hi Bandersnatch

Thought it may get complicated if more than one name corresponds to the same cell. 

As for the names not matching, it's because there were real names in there and I anonimysed them quickly before screen grabbing. When I originally created the matrix I manually plotted them (something I'd like to avoid in future).

Comment: Hi SC.  So there **could** be more than one name in a cell? Also, is it important for this to be a matrix of spreadsheet cells? It might be simpler to plot the x,y points on a scatter graph, and then label the points with the names.

Comment: Hi Bandersnatch, I did just that yesterday afternoon, clicking on the 'Work around image' link above, it'll show the outcome. Also one of my clever colleagues has almost solved it (is still working on displaying multiple names in one cell). I'll post the solution in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of my smart colleagues came up with this solution. Each cell in the matrix has this formula:

=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Stakeholders],MATCH($C$21&N3,Table1[Sub total A]&Table1[Sub total B],0)),"")

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1nmP.png)

It doesn't solve two names being in the same cell. But there is a solution for that involving a secondary data table that pulls the names  with the same values together (from the original data table). May tackle that in the future.